# Categorical Crossentropy for probailities distributions

Tags: python, deep-learning, probability-density, sparsecategoricalcrossentropy

I'm currently attempting to create a model that outputs a probability distribution for a discrete numeric dataset.

I know that categorical cross-entropy as a classification loss function, but if I bucket my numeric data and one-hot encode it could I then output probabilities for each of those buckets?

Is my thinking here correct? If not, what are some alternatives I could use to tackle this problem?

I have read about some binomial distribution predicting neural networks and believe I could go with that as well

Comment: What do you mean by "bucket my numeric data"? Can you give an example?

Comment: Lets say I have discrete values between 0 and 10,000. I could specify a bucket width of lets say 100, so I'd have 100 buckets. Each bucket represents a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you have pre-processed your target variable i.e. class number and assigned bin number to them.

As per the example you have provided in the comments if you have 10K classes and 100 bins then the mapping will be:

1. class [0-100) -> 0 i.e. bin 0
2. class [100-200) -> 1 i.e. bin 1 ..... (and so on)

Following the above example your one-hot encoder will have `num_classes` or `num_bins` elements or 100.

Then you just have to add `softmax` activation function in the output layer of your neural network that will return the probability distribution over the classes and you are good to go. To get the *bin* with the highest probability you just need to do `np.argmax(y_pred)` in case of a single instance and `np.argmax(y_pred, axis = 1)` in case of batch processing (I have used `numpy` assuming the output will be a `numpy.ndarray` but you can change this as you see fit).

**NOTE**: The neural network will only give the bin number. You will not get back the original class number from the bin number.

**Additional Information**: Check this [link](https://keras.io/api/losses/probabilistic_losses/#categoricalcrossentropy-class) to see how Categorical Cross-Entropy is used Keras Losses. *logits* is the *input to* the `softmax` activation function. In case you are using this or an implementation close to this then you can ignore the `softmax` activation on the output layer and calculate the loss from the logits itself.

Comment: Awesome yea what you laid out is what I'm currently doing I just wasn't sure if my approach was a viable way to achieve this. My data is slightly imbalanced, so I'm going to implement categorical focal cross-entropy, which should learn the harder cases better.

Comment: Nothing in deep learning or machine learning is off-the-shelf so keep experimenting. Please upvote or accept the answer if it solves your doubt.